# Can't install Visual Studio 2012 Express on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am getting following error when installing visual studio express edition on windows 8

> You need to restart your computer to continue the installation

Screenshot for illustration, it's the same screen for me, but it says Express instead of Ultimate:
[image]

I have restarted computer many times,but same problem comes each time.

Comment: Have you tried to run the installer as admin?

Comment: What comes after you _restart_?

Comment: Did you download ISO or Web-Installer? Try ISO if Web-installer was downloaded.

Comment: see my answer ,I got the screenshot from the link specified there.I forgot to take screenshot of my own version of visual studio.This is to help others...

Comment: What are the contents of the log file that is mentioned in the screenshot?

Comment: I have solved the problem,see my answer

Comment: "I have restarted computer many times" - Your solution might work fine, but it's more of a workaround. Can you tell me if you restarted by shutting down and powering up, or by using the restart option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I was able to solve my problem by following these steps :

1. first Open registry (as administrator) and browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
2. See if there is a string value "PendingFileRenameOperations" and check the value
3. if there is one, Rename the string value "PendingFileRenameOperations" to something similar to "PendingFileRenameOperationsrename"
4. reinstall VS2012 RC
5. after install VS2012 RC successfully, rename back the string value

I found these from here :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-NL/vssetup/thread/942fd4f7-9085-4cbf-bb98-a58706dbb693

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've downloaded the right Visual Studio 2012 for Windows 8. Also if something strucks please click Uninstall and then click Repair. I've got the same problem and I've been working with it since that fixed my error.

Comment: I have downloaded the right version,but it never installs due to error.how do i uninstall it then..

Comment: Go to Control Panel->Programs and Features and then double click on Miscrosoft Visual Studio 12 then Click OK and then reinstall it.

Comment: It was not even installed in the first place.anyways I have solved my problem and given the answer here.Thanks for any help