# Can't install any visual studio (express) on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio

i tried installing visual studio on my new win 8 computer, but i got the same error of this user [Can't install Visual Studio 2012 Express on Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/494605/cant-install-visual-studio-2012-express-on-windows-8) , i've tried his solution, changing registry values, but it didn't work.
i tried installing both via exe and iso, even 2013 prewiew

the log is avaible here: http://www.mediafire.com/?t3m8s515cc8dsq6

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PC needs a reboot according to the log:

> Condition 'RebootPending = 1' evaluates to true.
>
> Stop Block: SystemRebootPendingBlock : Per continuare l'installazione è necessario riavviare il computer. Riavviare il computer ed eseguire nuovamente l'installazione.

this means this:

To continue the installation you must restart the computer. Restart the computer and run the installation again.

Reboot (not shutdown!) and run the setup again

Comment: Just curious, is there any reason that shutting down/pressing the power button won't do the same thing as restarting?

Comment: Chipper of course not bit just restart in a case like this its faster

Comment: i thought shutdown->boot=reboot, i'll try

Comment: not in Windows 8. A shutdown here is logoff + hiberation.

Comment: thanks, it worked,there where some pending updates and i thought they belonged to the os, not to the application (that updated the framework i guess)